# Getting the Remainder using XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

1st time that i'll be writing this is in xslt (can be xslt 2 or 3). I would need the sum of all remainders. does anyone encountered this already? thank you.

here's the requirement:

```
2 IDs fields called id1 and id2. Each field has 6 chars (incl. space and decimal)

LEFT ALIGN:
    id1: 111   (3 spaces included here after 111) 

RIGHT ALIGN:
    id2: 123.50  (one decimal here)
```

I need to get first value A, B, C, D whereas:

```
    VALUE A: add up id1 from position 1 - 3
    VALUE B: add up id1 from position 4 - 6

    VALUE C: add up id2 from position 1 - 3
    VALUE D: add up id2 from position 4 - 6
```

NOTE: value of space is 20,  and decimal '.' is 15.

Sample Computation

```
id1: 111   (3 spaces included here)
    VALUE A: 3 (1+1+1) AND
    VALUE B: 60 (20+20+20)

id2: 123.50  (one decimal here)
    VALUE C: 5 (1+2+3) AND
    VALUE D: 20 (15+5)
Remainder= mod(abs((B+D)-(A+C)),13)

7 

Sum of all remainders: 7


Example 2:

Row 1:
LEFT ALIGN:
id1: 111   (3 spaces included here after 111) 

RIGHT ALIGN
id2: 123.50  

Row 2:
LEFT ALIGN:
id1: 321.50   

RIGHT ALIGN
id2:   222  (3 spaces before 111)

Row 1:
Value A: 3 (1+1+1)
Value B: 60 (20+20+20)
Value C: 6 (1+2+3)
Value D: 20 (15+5)

Row 2:
Value A: 6 (3+2+1)
Value B: 20 (15+5)
Value C:60 (20+20+20 
Value D: 6 (2+2+2)

Remainder= mod(abs((B+D)-(A+C)),13)

Row1: Remainder = mod(abs((60+20)-(3+6)),13)
Remainder = 6

Row 2:Remainder=mod(abs((20+6)-(6+6)),13)
Remainder = 1


Sum of all remainders: 7 (6+1) 

7 or the sum of all remainders will be included in the final output file.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you have `VALUE C: 5 (1+2+3)`, shouldn't that be `6`?

Comment: You forgot to provide the source XML document? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 3, one way might be to use accumulators:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" item-separator="&#10;"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="A" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data/id1"
        phase="end"
        select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(1, 3) => sum()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="B" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data/id1"
        phase="end"
        select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(4, 3) => sum()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="C" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data/id2"
        phase="end"
        select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(1, 3) => sum()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="D" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data/id2"
        phase="end"
        select="accumulator-after('values') => subsequence(4, 3) => sum()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="values" as="xs:integer*" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="data" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="data/id1/text() | data/id2/text()"
        select="analyze-string(.,'.')//*:match ! (
                  if (. = '.')
                  then 15
                  else if (. = ' ')
                  then 20
                  else xs:integer(.))"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="remainder" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data"
        phase="end"
        select="abs((accumulator-after('B') + accumulator-after('D')) -
                     (accumulator-after('A') + accumulator-after('C'))) mod 13"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="remainder-sum" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields" select="0"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data"
        select="$value + accumulator-after('remainder')"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>


  <xsl:output method="text" item-separator="&#10;"/>

  <xsl:template match="fields">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="accumulator-after('remainder-sum')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3bG/1

Of course you can only apply the code to the last element with

```
  <xsl:template match="fields[last()]">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="accumulator-after('remainder-sum')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

(instead of the `<xsl:template match="fields">` used earlier). See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3bG/2

Comment: Hi @Martin, thank you very much. based on your code, it's returning a sequence of totals (e.g. 6 7) is there a method I can use to get the last sequence or total? (e.g. I only need 7) thank you

Comment: Hi @Martin, I understand that you're using a node to sum up the values of the row value (e.g. <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="fields/data/id1"). But I'm trying to use a variable because the node value needs to be formatted first. When I try this <xsl:accumulator-rule
        match="$d1", it isnt working. The reason for this is because the d1 value doesnt have space. When the d1 value has only 2 digits, the xml input file just look like this <d1>12</d1>,i need to add the missing space so it can be added in the computation coz the char of the field should be always 6. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @QnA, consider to ask a new question about that problem, where you show the input you have, the result you want, the XSLT you have tried, any errors you got, all reduced to minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the problem. If the problem is about preprocessing the input to get it into a format you can use with the code of this answer then simply write a different mode or different stylesheet that first adds spaces or formatting as needed. If you need help with that, ask it as a separate question.